# How can I test a angular services that use current $location to get the current lo get the current host using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I created a test with jasmine that check is the services that is giving me the endpoint of the API is working. I am getting the default value because the application in unit test in not running in localhost. So how can I mock that feature in mu unit test.

Here is my unit test:

```
describe("EndpointService->", getApiEndPoint);

function getApiEndPoint() {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

    it("GetApiEndpointUriBaseOnCurrentHost", inject(function (endpointService) {
        //Arrange
        var expectedUriInLocalhostEnviroment = 'not recognized client host';

        //Act
        var uriEndPoint = endpointService.getApiEndpoint();
        //Assert 
        expect(uriEndPoint).toMatch(expectedUriInLocalhostEnviroment);

    }));
    };
```

This is my service. It is using `$location` to get the local host:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.factory('endpointService', endpointService);

    function endpointService($location) {
        return {
            getApiEndpoint: function () {
                var endpoint = '';
                var host = $location.host();
                switch ($location.host()) {
                    case 'localhost': endpoint = 'http://localhost:59987/'; break;
                    case 'projectDev': endpoint = 'http://project.com'; break;
                    default: endpoint = 'not recognized client host'; 
                }
                return endpoint;
            }
        }
    };

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Spy on the `host` method on the `$location` service and tell the spy to return the value you want. This same pattern can apply for any service, whether they are native Angular services or not.

```
var $location;

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function (_$location_) {
    $location = _$location_;

    spyOn($location, 'host');
}));

it('should get endpoint for localhost', function () {
    // Arrange
    $location.host.and.returnValue('localhost');
    var expected = 'http://localhost:59987/';

    // Act
    var uriEndPoint = endpointService.getApiEndpoint();

    // Assert 
    expect(uriEndPoint).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however if I try this solution I am having an error on the $location.host... line telling me that Can't find variable: $location. Should I include other thing?

Comment: forgot to include something. `$location` should be defined before it can be used in the tests. Updated the answer with this.

Comment: thanks. It is still not passing but the error is now that undefined is not and object (evaluation '$localtion.host') in the line of $location.host.and.returnValue('localhost')

Comment: if you are using an older version of jasmine with the `.andReturn` syntax, substitute it for that instead.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work  $location.host.andReturn.returnValue('localhost');. I am using the Jasmine 1.3.1.1 version. Maybe I should changed it to be 2.1.3 and is still not working in $location.host.and.returnValue('localhost'); Maybe I am missing something